# Does the Shapechange spell allow one to use Innate Spellcasting of the creature they turned into?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, spellcasting

The [*shapechange*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange) spell states that one does not get access to the Spellcasting trait of creatures they turn into:

> You transform into an average example of that creature, one without any class levels or the Spellcasting trait.

Does this restriction include monsters with Innate Spellcasting, or does one get the Innate Spellcasting trait of the creature they transform into?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### You get access to Innate Spellcasting when using *shapechange*

Spellcasting and Innate Spellcasting are both separate examples of special traits, as can be seen in [the basic rules for monsters](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#SpecialTraits). There are even monsters that have both traits, for example, the [Drow Mage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/drow-mage) (note how they even use a different spellcasting ability):

> **Innate Spellcasting.** The drow’s innate spellcasting ability is Charisma (spell save DC 12).
>
> **Spellcasting.** The drow is a 10th-level spellcaster. Its spellcasting ability is Intelligence (spell save DC 14, +6 to hit with spell attacks).

The *shapechange* spell explicitly states that you do not obtain  "**the** Spellcasting trait" (capitalized even) and not "any of its available spells" or anything similar<sup>1</sup> suggesting that only the trait that is called "Spellcasting" in particular is not obtained.

Further, Jeremy Crawford has also unofficially confirmed that these are supposed to be read as being different traits in [this tweet exchange](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/845737875211673601) that is also about *shapechange*:

> **Staffan Johansson** @DackeStaffan
> @JeremyECrawford When the shapechange spell says you don't get Spellcasting, does that include Innate Spellcasting?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
> Spellcasting and Innate Spellcasting are two different traits. #propernouns #DnD

Therefore, we can conclude that using *shapechange* grants access to the Innate Spellcasting trait along with any other special traits the creature has (except the Spellcasting trait).

---

<sup>1. Noted by [Medix2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/36521/medix2)</sup>